# Mapping through data in my state and creating new rows in my table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables

Currently I have a table that I'm trying to insert additional rows into after mapping through some data. There is 6 table-headers so naturally the data is divided up into 6 "table-data" sections. I'm trying to map through and create a new row for each object in the array of data. The data shows up in a new row as wanted, however, it is all placed in the first table-data section of that row. Please see code below.

**This is where I'm mapping through the data:

```
<div id="logs">
      <div className="container">
        <table className="highlight">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Attention</th>
              <th>Due In:</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {logs !== null && !loading ? (
              <TransitionGroup>
                {filtered !== null
                  ? filtered.map((log) => (
                      <CSSTransition
                        key={log._id}
                        timeout={300}
                        classNames="item"
                      >
                        <LogItem log={log} />
                      </CSSTransition>
                    ))
                  : logs.map((log) => (
                      <CSSTransition
                        key={log._id}
                        timeout={300}
                        classNames="item"
                      >
                        <LogItem log={log} />
                      </CSSTransition>
                    ))}
              </TransitionGroup>
            ) : (
              <Loader />
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div className="fixed-action-btn">
          <a
            href="#add-log-modal"
            className="btn-floating pulse btn-large green darken-2 modal-trigger tooltipped"
            data-tooltip="Open New Issue"
            data-position="left"
          >
            <i className="large material-icons">add</i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**This is where I'm creating the new table row:

```
const { deleteLog, setCurrent } = logContext;

  const { _id, title, attention, date, description, due } = log;

  const onDelete = () => {
    deleteLog(_id);
    M.toast({ html: "Log item has been removed" });
  };

  var dueDate = moment(due, "MMM DD, YYYY").fromNow(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td className="truncated">{description}</td>
        <td>
          {" "}
          <i
            className={`material-icons action ${
              attention === "Needs Attention" ? "red-text" : "green-text"
            }`}
          >
            {`${
              attention === "Needs Attention"
                ? "do_not_disturb_alt"
                : "done_all"
            }`}
          </i>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span
            className={`due-date ${
              dueDate <= "3"
                ? "green lighten-2"
                : dueDate <= "6"
                ? "amber lighten-2"
                : "red darken-1"
            }`}
          >
            <p>Due in {dueDate}</p>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a
            href="#edit-log-modal"
            className="modal-trigger"
            onClick={() => setCurrent(log)}
          >
            <i className="material-icons small card-link amber-text text-accent-2">
              edit
            </i>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          {" "}
          <a href="#!" onClick={onDelete} className="">
            <i className="material-icons small white-text card-link">delete</i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  );
```